# How to get GnuPG fingerpints only for specified key name, not for substring matches?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, fingerprint, openpgp

I have few GnuPG keys: test, test2, some test. When I invoke
`gpg --fingerprint test`, fingerprints of all keys are listed. When I run `gpg --fingerprint test2`, only test2 key fingerprint is printed. How can I list fingerprint only for key named test?

From the GnuPG manual page

> `--fingerprint [=names=]` List all keys with their fingerprints. This is the same output as `--list-keys` but with the additional output of a
>   line with the fingerprint. May also be combined with `--list-sigs` or
>   `--check-sigs`. If this command is given twice, the fingerprints of all secondary keys are listed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the documentation (`man gpg`) is the chapter "HOW TO SPECIFY A USER ID", pretty much at the end of the manual page.

The default mode is substring matching, which is what you observe (`test2` contains the substring `test`).

> **By substring match.**
>
> This is the default mode but applications may want to explicitly indicate this by putting the asterisk in front.  Match is not case sensitive.
>
> ```
> Heine
> *Heine
> ```

You want to use exact matches instead, where you have the options of matching words, a mail address or the whole user ID string depending on your specific needs:

> **By exact match on OpenPGP user ID.**
>
> This is denoted by a leading equal sign. It does not make sense for X.509 certificates.
>
> ```
> =Heinrich Heine <heinrichh@uni-duesseldorf.de>
> ```
>
> **By exact match on an email address.**
>
> This is indicated by enclosing the email address in the usual way with left and right angles.
>
> ```
> <heinrichh@uni-duesseldorf.de>
> ```
>
> **By word match.**
>
> All words must match exactly (not case sensitive) but can appear in any order in the user ID or a subjects name.  Words are any
>   sequences of letters,  digits,  the  under‐
>             score and all characters with bit 7 set.
>
> ```
> +Heinrich Heine duesseldorf
> ```